# Django FieldError and AttributeError exceptions after adding new field to model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing a multipurpose web application, and the data model is somewhat in flux.

I have a class `Client` defined as

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column = "client_id")
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100L, unique = True)
    parentorg = models.ForeignKey("Parentorgs")
    demo_client = models.IntegerField()
    live_client = models.IntegerField(db_column = "live_client")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'txn_client'
```

The last field, `live_client`, has just been added.  This is a fliter field to differentiate between active and inactive `Client` objects.  Rather than relying on a data migration, I simply did an `ALTER TABLE` statement in MySQL to add the field and set to 1 the relevant records.  This has worked in the past with zero issues.

In my view method, I have

```
from app.models import Client

def index(request):
    client_list = Client.objects.filter(live_client = 1)
```

Suddenly, this is throwing a FieldError, because Django `cannot resolve keyword 'live_client' into a field`, and displays some alternative keywords.

To make sure that the model record was replicating the database table, I ran

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

and the `Client` class in `models.py` replicated the `inspectdb` printout.

For further testing, I changed the index method to

```
def index(request):
client_list = Client.objects.all()

for c in client_list:
    print c.live_client
```

This in turn threw an AttributeError stating that `'Client' object has no attribute 'live_client'`

Now, this is completely contradicting what is defined in both `models.py` and the printout from `python manage.py inspectdb`

Comment: Have you deployed your new codes?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by deploy?  I'm working on a local dev machine, using the standard django runserver command.

Comment: Have you restarted your server?  I think what @iMom0 was getting at is that because you did this outside of django it may have gotten confused if you didn't restart the runserver command.

Comment: @rh0dium, I restarted the server multiple times.

Comment: Hey just thinking this through.. ("1" != 1).  Can you do this on the SQL side..  SHOW CREATE TABLE <CLIENT> - I wonder if you have an issue with the column type..

Comment: @rh0dium, interesting thought.  Originally, the `live_client` column showed an int(11) field, so I changed it to int(10) but the error still occurs.  So I just modified the filter query to use Q objects and get based on a set of client_ids

Comment: I will say through this it should be very apparent why South rocks..  This becomes trivial ;)